# Logging conditionally repetitively in code

Tags: java, logging

I am using Log4j2 for logging. Multiple operations return success code. If status `0` is received, it means operation is successful, else failed. If operation is successfully, I log `"*** is successfully."` and if it fails I logs `"*** failed with status : " + status`. This is kind of repetitive  in code.

```
public class ReadCallbackManager {

  //Log Object
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ReadCallbackManager.class);

  private static ReadCallback readCallback;

  private static final int SUCCESS_STATUS = 0;

  public int setHook(final ICallback aCallBack) {

    readCallback = new ReadCallback(aCallBack);

    final int status = readCallback.setHook();

    if (status == SUCCESS_STATUS) {
      LOGGER.info("Read callback hook is set successfully!!!");
    } else {
      LOGGER.info("Read Callback hook set failed with status : " + status);
    }

    return status;

  }

}
```

So I though to create a wrapper around the Logger class to handle this if else condition as below:

```
public final class BacStacLogger {

  public static final int SUCCESS_STATUS = 0;

  //Log Object
  private Logger logger;

  public BacStacLogger(final Class<?> className) {
    if (logger == null) {
      logger = LogManager.getLogger(className);
    }
  }

  public void infoHookByStatus(final int status, final String successMessage, final String failureMessage) {
    if (status == SUCCESS_STATUS) {
      logger.info(successMessage);
    } else {
      logger.info(failureMessage + " : " + status);
    }
  }

}
```

And I have updated my previous code as :

```
public class ReadCallbackManager {

  //Log Object
  private static final ProjectLogger LOGGER = ProjectLogger(ReadCallbackManager.class);

  private static ReadCallback readCallback;

  public int setHook(final ICallback aCallBack) {

    readCallback = new ReadCallback(aCallBack);

    final int status = readCallback.setHook();

    LOGGER.infoHookByStatus(status, "Read hook set successfully.", "Read hook set failed.");

    return status;

  }

}
```

Would you please provide your comments on it? Or if required, any improvements?

Comment: You might be over thinking this. To my eyes, it feels like you replaced an `if` statement with a lot more code. If it is not a matter of relevance may be consider logging the `status` directly `LOGGER.info("Read callback hook response " + status);` On the encapsulation itself, I think that is a good solution if you anticipate future uses, for now I'd keep it simple.

Comment: Side note: You are using the name `LOGGER`, indicating that you consider it to be a constant. According to the Google Java Style Guide: "*Constants are static final fields whose contents are deeply immutable and **whose methods have no detectable side effects.** This includes primitives, Strings, immutable types, and immutable collections of immutable types.* (...)" A `Logger` object has a side effect and is therefore not a constant. [Source](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.4-constant-names) - with logger as an explicit example

Comment: @Bhaskar In some cases it's easier to change your requirements than the code, I totally agree with you! I would recommend posting that as an answer. If needed, the message can even contain "success: true" or "success: false" by evaluating the boolean value within the log message. Also, avoid string concatenation in logging, use this instead: `logger.info("Read callback hook response: {}, success: {}", status, status == SUCCESS_STATUS)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few remarks that come to my mind.

### Simplifying the logic

In your sample code, the two different log strings for success and failure don't differ too much. So I guess the following strings might be acceptable to you as well:

```
"Setting read callback hook: successful"
"Setting read callback hook: FAILED with status nnn"
```

Then you can create a static method `statusText(int status)` e.g. in a `Utils` class that returns `"successful"` for status==0 and `"FAILED with status nnn"` in all other cases. If I understood correctly, such a `statusText()` method should be re-usable all over your application, assuming that 0 always means success.

And then you can do the logging like:

```
LOGGER.info("Setting read callback hook: " + Utils.statusText(status));
```

But there are a few other issues:

### Log Levels

Log4J has different log levels, and you shouldn't ignore that aspect. Depending on the consequences, a failure should typically get the ERROR level, at least the WARN level. So, in case of a non-zero status, `LOGGER.error()` seems to be a better choice.

INFO is meant for messages useful to the system administrator running the site. Messages targetting the developer should get a lower level, typically DEBUG or TRACE. I guess, the success of setting some callback isn't important to the system admin. The admin typically only wants to see things needing his/her special attention. So, I'd change the success case to `LOGGER.debug()`.

Of course, then my `statusText()` solution no longer fits, as that doesn't support different log levels.

### Why not Exceptions?

Your code sticks to the 1970s status code pattern to communicate failure (return an integer where some values mean success and others mean failure). By the 1990s, the software industry had learned that error handling can be done in a better way using exceptions.

So, instead of returning `int` values and forcing each and every layer of your software to check for the success results, throw an exception if something like setting a callback failed. By embracing exceptions as the signal of failure, your code typically becomes

- cleaner,
- more readable,
- more compact,
- more focussed on the main task instead of the failures
- and more robust.

The simple guidelines for exceptions are:

- If a method can't fulfill its job (whatever you defined that job to be), it throws an exception.
- If a method returns normally, the caller can rely on the fact it has successfully done its job.
- You catch an exception only if you know a way how to continue successfully even after an internal failure, e.g. by retrying.